How to prove this MAC to be secure (or not)?
Suppose a fixed pseudorandom generator $G$ with expansion factor $l$, and consider:

$Gen$, on input $1^n$, outputs a binary string $k$ drawn uniformly at random from $\{0,1\}^n$
$Mac$, on input $k \in \{0,1\}^n$ and $m \in \{0,1\}^{l(n)}$, draws at random $r \in \{0,1\}^{l(n)}$ and outputs the pair $\langle r, G(k) \oplus m \oplus r \rangle$, where $\oplus$ is the bitwise xor.
$Vrfy$, on inputs $m,r,t,k$, calculates $t'=G(k) \oplus m \oplus r$ and checks if $t'==t$. If yes, it outputs one.

Is $\Pi$ secure? yes or not? I tried everything, I suppose not because $G$ is fixed, and this should somehow break the security, but I didn't manage to find a formal proof of it. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Hint: how does a MAC of $m'$ differ from a MAC of $m$?

@Mikero can't you just tell me?

https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/do-we-want-to-update-the-way-we-handle-homework-questions

Hint': What happens if you calculate t XOR r?
